# user training enviroment

Tags: sandbox, bestpractice, etl

We're in the process of researching how to setup a user training environment. We're currently doing user training in the production org, and want to get a away from that. We've got over 2,500 users so there is a pretty constant need for training.

In terms of environment type, has anyone successfully used dev orgs or scratch orgs for user training? These would be the least expensive environments, so any reason not to use them?

Also, has anyone got a recommendation on the most efficient way to populate the orgs with training data? I know there are a lot of options and just trying to narrow my focus to a few alternatives to research further.

Comment: You should use a full sandbox for this type of training.

Comment: To use scratch orgs for user training you would need to invest heavily in setup automation and data seeding. Otherwise, they will look nothing like your production org.

Answer (score 0):

You should use either full copy/partial copy sandboxes for User Training.

Full Copy - Costly in terms of licenses but no need to worry of Data, as all your data will be in sync with production with frequent refresh.

Partial Copy - Cheaper than full copy but you need to define certain steps to feed important data only which is used frequently by the users and covers major/main functionalities.
It will be a tedious task for the first time but later you can pass this to your QA team